# How to iterate a string using while loop in C++?

Tags: c++11

```
number = 100010001111111

for (int i=0; number.length(); i++) {
    while number[i] == 1 {
    k++;
    }
}
```

I would like to implement a while-loop as a replacement for the for-loop as shown above.

How could I convert this to a while-loop?

Comment: while number[i] == 1 {
        k++;
        } 
will never get out of the loop if the number at i is 1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for the problem you mentioned in your comment ([Problem - 96A](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/96/A))

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Please enter your players situation" << endl; 
    std::string str;
   cin >> str;

std::string::size_type i = 0;
int NumbersofAppearances = 0;
int ConsectiveNumberSequence = 7; //You can change that to whatever sequence you like
bool IsDangerous=false;
while (i < str.size())
{

     if(str[i]=='1'  )
     {
         ++NumbersofAppearances;
         //We need to check if we reached the consecutive number or not and save it on a different bool variable
         if(NumbersofAppearances>=ConsectiveNumberSequence)
         IsDangerous=true;
     }
     else
     {
        NumbersofAppearances=0; 
     }
    ++i;
}

//print out the end result
if (IsDangerous)
cout <<"YES , this is dangerous"<< endl;
else
cout <<"No, this is not dangerous"<< endl;

   return 0;
}
```

And here's a link to [Coding ground](http://goo.gl/JwMnch)

Comment: I want to know if number has continuous 'n' 1's or 0's. The solution perhaps will not give me that.

Comment: Did you try it? the solution will iterate trough each character and k++ if the number is 1

Comment: The solution will give me total no. of 1's but I need only 'continuous' 1's.

Comment: you need to know how many continuous 1 in your string right? so let's say we have 0101110101101111011  k should be 11?

Comment: One way to achieve that is to follow a recursive approach and also your question is not clear please edit it and provide more info for others to help

Comment: @AmitaSinghChauhan check out the solution i proposed